# I am writing unit test case for the method "execute" inside this method private method is calling to open and read file

Tags: c#, nunit

this is my class file

```
public override void Execute(IParserContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

_fileProcessors.Add("disks.json", (file) => { ProcessJson<JsonModels.Disk.Class1, TableModels.Disk>(file); });
foreach (var parentFile in context.Files)
        {
            foreach (var childFile in parentFile.Children.Where(x => filesToProcess.Contains(x.FileName.ToLowerInvariant())))
            {
                Action<IParserFile> action;

                if (_fileProcessors.TryGetValue(childFile.FileName, out action))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        action.Invoke(childFile);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        childFile.Log.Error($"Unhandled Exception: {childFile.FileName}\n{ex.Message}", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

when the "invoke" method is called inside try block its calling "ProcessJson" private method. below is the code of "ProcessJson"

```
private void ProcessJson<TSource, TDest>(IParserFile parserFile) where TDest : IParserTableRecord
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(parserFile.Open()))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var table = _context.GetTable<TDest>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    TSource sourceRecord = serializer.Deserialize<TSource>(reader);
                    var destRecord = _mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>(sourceRecord);
                    table.Insert(destRecord, parserFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when this method is called i am getting error at `while (reader.Read())`  how to set "JsonTextReader" in my test class?

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: You need to use a MemoryStream when not reading data from a file.  The memory stream can be used with a StreamReader : new StreamReader(ms) where ms is the memory stream filled with data.

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream'                                                                                            
          This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Teneo.Parsers.PowerProtect.PowerProtectParser.ProcessJson<TSource, TDest>(Teneo.Core.Parser.IParserFile) in PowerProtectParser.cs

Comment: @jdweng can you share the code snippet. i am new to Nunit testing

Comment: Look for MemoryStream at following :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/?force_isolation=true